# form #type => checkboxes with zero / empty option value

Tags: 7, forms

I am building something which uses a form element with `'#type' => 'checkboxes'`.

I want this to be reusable, so it should accept anything as option values that works as a PHP array key (integers and non-integer strings).

```
$form['checkboxes'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => [
    0 => 'zero',
    '' => 'empty string',
    ' ' => 'space',
    'other' => 'Other',
  ],
];
```

However there seems to be a problem with values `0` (zero) and `''` (empty string).

Even when the checkboxes for '' or 0 are checked, the values are gone in the `$element['#value']` array, e.g. when checking with a custom '#element_validate' callback.

```
$element['#value'] === [
  # '' and 0 are gone, even if they were checked.
  ' ' => ' ',
  'other' => 'other',
];
```

Interestingly, the `$_POST` still contains the values, with an interesting twist, where space and empty string behave like array insertion via `[]`. I suppose this is due to the way POST data is sent.

```
$_POST['checkboxes'] === [
  0 => '0',
  1 => '',
  2 => ' ',
  'other' => 'other',
];
```

I can imagine why all of this happens, but is there a workaround or solution?

EDIT: The previous version of the code snippet was misleading, sorry. I had mixed up $_POST and the original '#options' array.

Comment: Why would you put an empty string in the first place? Try putting zero without quotes `0 => 0,`

Comment: Sorry, my code snippet was misleading. I fixed it.

Comment: "Why would you put an empty string in the first place?" - I want this component to be usable by others, and I assume that empty string would be a valid option value.

Comment: _Even when the checkboxes for '' or 0 are checked, the values are rejected later on_ What does _rejected_ in there mean exactly? What's rejecting them (and how)? Are you sure you're not just running the standard `array_filter` on them which is naturally clearing those empty values out of the array?

Comment: @Clive They are gone in e.g. #element_validate. I updated the question. I think the array_filter(), or something equivalent, happens somewhere in the form element handlers.

Comment: But now I am no longer sure. On the website where I tested this, a strange module 'value_is' is installed, this adds a #value_callback t the 'checkboxes' type. I should test this somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, after Drupal gets its dirty mitts on it you mean. Yeah that makes sense. Have a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_checkboxes/7.x and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_process_checkbox/7.x, I don't have time to look at the moment but the comments specifically talk about '0' and '' as return values for checkboxes, so you might be able to get a start point to debug in there

Comment: One interesting observation: Sending an array like `['x' => ['' => 5]]` via GET or POST gives us `['x' => [0 => 5]]`, because PHP does not recognize `[]` as an empty string array key when parsing the query. I wonder how an empty string array key could be encoded in the query.

Comment: You could always 'preprocess' your options by concatenating a prefix (e.g., `'_'`) to it when creating the form elements and remove that prefix in the submit handler. Thus, a key like `0` would become `'_0'`, `''` becomes `'_'`, `' '` becomes `'_ '`, and so on.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz It's a good idea. In my case the submit handler is not a good place because the form component might be nested somewhere deep in the form array, and the submit handler does not know the location. But the transformation could be done in the #value_callback perhaps, and the other direction in #process.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to prevent this problem by adding an '#element_validate' handler on the checkboxes element.

The code below is a simplified version of what I did, up to you to fine-tune.

```
$element['#element_validate'][] = '_MYMODULE_checkboxes_validate';

function _MYMODULE_checkboxes_validate(array &$element, array &$form_state) {

  // The form value already has the format $[$id] = $id, mostly.
  // However, if trim($id) === '', the array key will be an integer increment.
  $value = $element['#value'];

  // Make sure it has the expected format.
  if (!is_array($value) || [] === $value) {
    $ids = [];
  }
  else {
    // Get rid of integer keys for empty-ish string ids.
    $ids = array_combine($value, $value);
  }

  // Remove dangling * => 0 entries.
  form_set_value($element, $ids, $form_state);
}
```

Note: If you have the [value_is](https://drupal.org/project/value_is) module installed, empty-ish values will always be unset, thanks to `_value_is_disabled_options_value_callback()`.